Why do patsubst and subst not work when the pattern is a function's return value in a Makefile?
I have a Makefile with two targets, new and new2, which are intended to use the patsubst and subst functions to remove or replace a specific string from a path. The functions work as expected in the new target, but they do not work in the new2 target when the pattern or replacement is derived from a function's return value.
Here is my Makefile:
path := .././../log
from := log
new:
    @echo "new------------"
    @echo $(path)
    @echo $(from)
    @echo $(patsubst %$(from),%,$(path))
    @echo $(subst $(from),, $(path))

define get_log
    log
endef

from2 := $(call get_log, $(path))
new2:
    @echo "new2------------"
    @echo $(path)
    @echo $(from2)
    @echo $(patsubst %$(from2),%,$(path))
    @echo $(subst $(from2),, $(path))

When I run make new new2, I get the following output:
new------------
.././../log
log
.././../
.././../
new2------------
.././../log
log
.././../log
.././../log


You are obscuring the simple and obvious debugging help you can get from make itself. Don't litter your recipes with @. Use make -s when you genuinely don't care what it's doing.
To aid debugging I took out the @ decorations and added single quotes around the arguments to echo.
bash$ make new2
new2------------
echo '.././../log'
.././../log
echo '    log'
    log
echo '.././../log'
.././../log
echo ' .././../log'
 .././../log

The formatting in your question is slightly erratic but with these changes, I'm hoping you can figure out what's wrong.
